# How to stop RewriteRule from removing trailing slash

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess file inside my "fs" folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Basically I want all urls to be sent to the index.php file, but I need to preserve the trailing slashes in my urls.  The RewriteRule always seems to remove the trailing slash from the urls and I need to keep them.

`http://example.com/fs/path/` gets redirected to `http://example.com/fs/path`

How can I prevent the trailing slashes from being removed?  I need the trailing slash to remain.  Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

**Edit**
Here is the parent .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^auth(.*)$ auth.php?$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ file.php?path=/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ css.php?path=/$1 [NC]

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Comment: This rule doesn't (can't) remove trailing slash. Do you have other rules too?

Comment: That is my entire .htaccess file inside this folder.  I have another .htaccess file in the parent folder.  Could that be causing the problem?  Is there a way to ignore the one from the parent folder if it is?

Comment: Can you show parent .htaccess code?

Comment: Just added the parent .htaccess to original post

Comment: Ok good. Is `/fs/path` a real directory? And does it have a .htaccess also?

Comment: /fs is a real path, but /fs/path is not.  It's something I'm passing to the /fs/index.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your `/fs/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /fs/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: That still changes the url and removes the trailing slash.  Would there be some sort of apache conf setting that is doing this?

Comment: Most likely there are some rules there. Run this request in firebug and see what you get in net tab.

Comment: GET /fs/Projects/ 301 Moved Permanently 
          GET Projects 200 OK

Comment: Oops.  I found out that I'm using a Laravel installation which is doing the redirect when a trailing slash is found.  So it's not a problem with the .htaccess file.  Thanks for the help!